# Grouping dataframe based on a gap between column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

Let's say we have the following dataset:

```
Name    Num

First    1
Second   50
Third    110
Fourth   2
Fifth    58
Sixth    105
Seventh  8
```

I want to group the dataframe based on a maximum gap of (for example) 10 between each row of the *num* column. So, for example, I would like to have:

```
Name                   Num
First,Fourth,Seventh   1,2,8
Second,Fifth           50,58
Sixth,Third            105,110
```

I tried with [Raymond Hettinger's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783947/grouping-clustering-numbers-in-python), but I need to group the dataframe, not only the column, because I want to do a barplot after.
I tried with this (I sorted the dataframe based on the column, first):

```
    for idx,val in enumerate(df_sorted['num'], start=1):
    if idx == 1:
        groups =[df_sorted.iloc[idx]]
    elif abs(data['pos'][idx] - data['pos'][idx-1]) <= 10:
        groups[-1].append(data.iloc[idx,:])
    else:
        groups.append(data.iloc[idx,:])
```

But I'm having some problem understanding how lists work in Python (I always used them in R).
Don't know if there is an easier way using *groupby* or something else (like *Grouper* for time series).

**EDIT:**
At the very end, I choose the following approach to solve the problem, using Raymond Hettinger's Answer:

```
def cluster(data, maxgap, column):
'''Arrange data into groups where successive elements
   differ by no more than *maxgap*
'''
#data.sort() #sort data if necessary
groups = list()
groups = [[data.iloc[0,:]]]

for idx,val in enumerate(data[column]):
    if idx > 0:
        if abs(val - data[column][idx-1]) <= maxgap:
            groups[-1].append(data.iloc[idx,:])
        else:
            groups.append([data.iloc[idx,:]])
return groups
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We binned the numbers to calculate the distribution and then grouped and listed them according to that distribution; N=24 is intentionally tailored to your expected results. Thresholds may be more difficult to set for actual operations. For example, for every 10 categories, 50 and 58 would be a different group.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Name Num
First 1
Second 50
Third 110
Fourth 2
Fifth 58
Sixth 105
Seventh 8
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df.sort_values('Num', ascending=True, inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
N = 24
category = pd.cut(df['Num'], bins=np.arange(df['Num'].min(), df['Num'].max()+ N, N), right=False)

category.value_counts()
[1, 25)      3
[97, 121)    2
[49, 73)     2
[73, 97)     0
[25, 49)     0
Name: Num, dtype: int64

df.groupby(category).agg(list)
    Name    Num
Num     
[1, 25) [First, Fourth, Seventh]    [1, 2, 8]
[25, 49)    []  []
[49, 73)    [Second, Fifth] [50, 58]
[73, 97)    []  []
[97, 121)   [Sixth, Third]  [105, 110]
```

Comment: This is an interesting way to solve the problem, thanks. However, I choose, at the end, another approach (using lists) that fits best my problem. I edited my post.